# Parsing txt using python sets data structure

Tags: python

[image: text file format]

how can i parse this so that I can obtain how many unique urls there are regardless of the number behind it ? using python

Comment: What is that, some file that you are reading? Please provide more information.

Comment: yes it is just a txt file in this format

Comment: "how can i parse this so that I can obtain how many unique urls there are regardless of the number behind it ? using python" – By writing a program in Python which parses this file, then asking questions on [so] if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the file and get the lines as a string using:

```
with open("/path/to/file.txt") as file:
    lines = list(file)
```

This will give you a list of all lines in the text file.
Now since you do not want duplicates, I think using set would be a good way. (Set does not contain duplicates)

```
answer=set()
for x in lines:
   answer.add(x[x.find(" ")+1:x.rfind(":")])
```

This will iterate through all the lines and add the part after the space till and not including the : to the set, which will handle the case for duplicates. Now answer should contain all the unique urls

Tested for Python3.6

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to parse and extract uids from your file line per line.

```
import re

uids = set()
with open('...') as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.match('$[a-z0-9]+', line)
        if m:
            uids.add(m.group(0))

print(len(uids))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
A, List = ("String_1   URL_1:10\nString_2   URL_2:20\nString_3   URL_1:30".replace("   ", ",")).split("\n"), []
for x in range(len(A)):
    Result = re.search(",(.*):", A[x])
    if Result.group(1) not in List:
        List.append(Result.group(1))
print(len(List))
```

This should solve your problem.